# How to check number of times a Weight Tensor has been updated in TensorFlow?

Tags: python, python-3.x, tensorflow

I have a simple question. I have created my own weights using `tf.get_variable`. For debugging purposes I need to check how many times the weights have been updated, i.e. how many times the optimizer have actually updated the weight?

How can this be done? If you require my code I can provide it.

Comment: According to the batch size and the epoch you can compute how many back propagation you've made.

Comment: @politinsa that is not my point..I want to explicitly check...that is apparently what TF is doing..

Comment: Can you show your own attempt at counting such updates?

Comment: @E_net4 i have no idea how to do it...i only have the understanding that a counter has to somehow be included in the computational graph

Comment: Consider doing some research on creating your own TensorFlow variables for that purpose.

Answer (score 1):

That is usually called in TensorFlow the "global step", and it has some helper functions for it:

```
global_step = tf.train.create_global_step()
optimizer.minimize(loss, global_step=global_step)
```

[`tf.train.get_global_step`](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/train/get_global_step) really just creates a variable, but making sure it is not trainable and adding it to the right collections. You also have [`tf.train.get_global_step`](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/train/get_global_step) so you can do:

```
optimizer.minimize(loss, global_step=tf.train.create_global_step())
```

And at some other point in the code retrieve the tensor like:

```
global_step = tf.train.get_global_step()
```

Moreover, you can use [`tf.train.get_or_create_global_step`](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/train/get_or_create_global_step) if you are not sure which part of the graph definition will go first.

The is one more function, [`tf.train.global_step`](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/train/global_step), but I don't think it serves any purpose currently, since it just runs the given tensor in the given session and returns its value as an integer.

Comment: I'll check it tomorrow..Thanks for the answer